# Access Array Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel

I use DB::connection to access another database I got right result

```
$query = 'select organisation from organisations where id = '.$datum->organisation_id . ' LIMIT 1';

$organisation  = DB::connection('mysql2')->select($query);
```

and here is the result:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#2318 ▼
    +"organisation": "XYZ Bank"
  }
]
```

my problem is I don;t know how to access the name of the organisation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can access using

```
$organisation[0]->organisation
```

but instead of queries like that you can use [Laravel query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries)

```
$organisation  = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('organisations')->where('id',$datum->organisation_id)->select('organisation')->first();
```